# Different authentication forms for different folders

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET website with two different sections, root website and an /Admin sub-folder. I want to have two different forms authentication/login pages for them. /Admin folder should use/redirect /Admin/Login.aspx and root pages should use /Login.aspx. What should I do in web.config to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple options:

- Use the same authentication form. Then use roles to authorize access to admin
- Allow access to the login form by adding a location + authorize anonymous rule to the login's form path. Hook to events at the global.asax in order to redirect to the admin's login on unauthenticated/unauthorized access of /admin pages if that's desired.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at roles authentication?

> You are building an Intranet expense report application for your organization, and want to enable role-based authentication and authorization capabilities within it.  Specifically, you want to create logical roles called 'approvers', 'auditors', and 'administrators' for the application, and grant/deny end-users access to functionality within the application based on whether they are in these roles.

Something along the lines of [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/Recipe_3A00_-Implementing-Role_2D00_Based-Security-with-ASP.NET-2.0-using-Windows-Authentication-and-SQL-Server.aspx)