# asp.net authorization for many different folders

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging

I am using asp.net (c#).

**Problem:**

I need to allow users to login from different pages:

```
www.mypage.com/login.aspx
www.mypage.com/orgs/org-1/login.aspx
www.mypage.com/orgs/org-2/login.aspx
www.mypage.com/orgs/org-3/login.aspx
```

... where 1, 2, 3 etc. Organization IDs.

Currently, when I open www.mypage.com/orgs/org-1/login.aspx user is redirected to www.mypage.com/login.aspx

**Whole story:**
I have an application that was not coded by me. It has a main login page (www.mypage.com/login.aspx).
But it has also many different login pages - every organization has its own login page that is located in folder Orgs/Org-ID/login.aspx. This is necessary because organizations wants to have different color schemes, logo, some extra information, custom welcome statements and other custom things on their login page.

I was not working on it before, but the scheme now is following: 
1) www.mypage.com/login.aspx is base login page; everyone can login from this page. It works.
2) there is a file OrgLogin.aspx (note that **CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" !!!!**) that contains some custom login page for organizations. It differs from Login.aspx a bit, but uses the same CodeBehind.

3) When application administrator creates new organization from application interface, then OrgLogin.aspx file is copied to a location www.mypage.com/**orgs/org-1/login.aspx** (where 1 is organization id and it changes) and also renames this file to Login.aspx.
Every login.aspx file then could be customized by the organization admins if they want to. If they do not want, then default page is used.

So far it is clear, but the following is not working:
4) It is necessary to allow users to login from different pages:
www.mypage.com/orgs/org-1/login.aspx -> displays login.aspx from appropriate folder (Login.aspx.cs from root folder is CodeBehind)
www.mypage.com/orgs/org-2/login.aspx
...
Currently, when I navigate to www.mypage.com/orgs/org-2/login.aspx system redirects user to www.mypage.com/login.aspx?returnurl....

**EDIT**
The full structur of folder would be the following:
orgs/org-*/login.aspx -> should be accessable without redirecting to root login 
orgs/org-*/forgotpassword.aspx -> should be accessable without redirecting to root forgotpassword
orgs/org-*/document (folder) -> should not be accessable without authentication
orgs/org-*/images (folder) -> should not be acessable without authentication

I have read some sollutions when there are only two different folders and usually they are with different roles (admin and non-admin), for example, [Different authentication forms for different folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012655/different-authentication-forms-for-different-folders).

But this is not my case.

Comment: Is it redirecting the users as soon as they go to the login page or after they've logged in? If it's after they've logged in it sounds like the login script itself is doing it.

Answer (score 1):

if your `orgs/org-*` folder only contains the `OrgLogin.aspx` page, you can place a `web.config` file to allow access to the page/avoid redirection. the content of this `web.config` file would be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>    
    <system.web>
        <authorization>             
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>    
</configuration
```

### update

to allow specific page, you can use the location tag like this

```
<configuration>
   <location path="Login.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>       
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have updated my post. You can see that there are some other subfolders (not files) in given directory that should not be accessed without authentication. And it also contains ForgotPassword.aspx that is also customized.

Comment: Where should I add this web.config? Note thingat org-* folder is created dynamically by the system. Note hat I do have only login and not orglogin page. Orglogin.aspx is just a template to copy and rename to login.aspx.

Comment: @renathy this web.config should be inside the org-* folder. you can manually copy-paste the file in every folder when you copy orglogin.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You could use URL rewriting for this (as long as your on .NET 3.5 SP1 +).  Your flow would  be along the lines of:

1. `www.mypage.com/orgs/org-2/login.aspx` is  rewritten to `www.mypage.com/login.aspx` with org-2 stored in the route values
2. login.aspx queries a DB with all the custom color scheme, logo, etc information for that organization and configures the page appropriately (or if the route value is empty, it shows the defaults)
3. All the actual login code is on *one page*, ie `www.mypage.com/login.aspx`.  This avoids all the redirect type issues.

Comment: This doesn't work, because orgs/org-1/login.aspx is different from orgs/org-2/login.aspx etc. When organization is created then those pages are the same, but organization admin can customize login.aspx view page. So I cannot really use only one login.aspx view page.

Comment: You can give the organization admin customization access with this setup, you just save their changes to the DB.  With css, you can really give them almost 100% control over the look and feel of the login page and still keep it all on one physical page.

Comment: It is a requirement to allow organization admins to edit login.aspx page "by hand". I do not have possibility to save their changes in DB.